# Pre-Flight Http 'OPTIONS' Method being sent instead of 'DELETE'

Tags: http, methods, cors, http-delete

I've been stuck on this for a few hours with no luck, so I figured that I would ask here.

I have a service with a bunch of endpoints, most of which accept `GET` and `POST` http methods. In that case, my service simply specifies `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be `*` in the response headers, in the event that one of my apps is on a different domain/port and wants to use the service.

I have **one** endpoint that uses the `DELETE` http method, and I can't seem to get it to work. When I call this endpoint from my client app, I get this message in my console:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've been reading up on CORS for the past couple hours and have tried a few different things, all of which have not worked. I (think I) at least understand that when I'm using http methods other than `GET` and `POST`, the browser sends a pre-flighted request with `OPTIONS` as the http method.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there a way to disable this pre-flighted request? I specify in my client app that the http method to call this endpoint is `DELETE`. Should I be putting something specifying headers in my AJAX function that calls this endpoint (I'm using straight JavaScript)?

If I can't figure out a way around this, I'm just going to change my endpoint to use a `GET` or `POST` method, but I wanted to find a way to handle this issue before I took the easy way out.

Comment: Did you solve it? Did you add the headers at server side as pointed in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I (think I) at least understand that when I'm using http methods other than `GET` and `POST`, the browser sends a pre-flighted request with `OPTIONS` as the http method.

Yes

> Is there a way to disable this pre-flighted request?

No there isn’t. It’s initiated by browsers automatically, with no way to disable it from your JS. As long as you’re sending that `DELETE` request cross-origin in your JS, browsers will do that preflight.

> Should I be putting something specifying headers in my AJAX function that calls this endpoint?

Given the “*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*” message you’re getting, no changes you make in your client code will make any difference.

The place where more headers need to be sent to deal with this is instead on the server side.

> If I can't figure out a way around this, I'm just going to change my endpoint to use a `GET` or `POST` method

You might want to experiment with trying that first. It seems even if you make that change you’re still gonna get that “*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*”.

The SO question ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) is a good place to read up on this to get a better idea of what’s happening.